# Getting data from database and update for a particular record in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm fetching the data from database for a particular record using email id in the hidden field.

If I try to add as `input type="text"` it is not working for me, can any one check this.

Here is my code.

**Index.php:**

```
<?php
  session_start();

  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
  if($username) { 
?>
  <h3> Welcome <?php echo $username; ?></h3>
<?php 
  } else { 
    echo "no"; 
  }
?>
<html>
  <body>        
    <table class="table table-hover">
     <form action="personalinfo.php" METHOD="POST"> 
      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $username;?>" name="email">
      <tr>
        <th><label for="first_name">Name</label></th>
      </tr>

      <?php
        include "personalinfo.php";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo "<tr>";
          <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $row->first_name;?>" />  
          echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
      ?>
     </form>
    </body>
  </html>
```

**personalinfo.php :**

```
<?php
  $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
  $db = mysql_select_db("accountant", $connection);
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registered where email='$username'");
?>
```

In index.php,  if I use like this in while condition 'first_name';?> name="first_name"/> so that I can update the record  but if i remove this

```
echo "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . "</td>";
```

and if I add like this instead of that echo

```
<?php echo $row->first_name;?>
```

it gives error as

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index\index.php on line 44
```

Comment: if i use <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $row->first_name;?>"> also it is getting the same error

Comment: Cause your fetching as an array, not an object.

Comment: Your html is full of errors, try to use an IDE !

Comment: Iam not getting you can you please tell me

Comment: but it is getting the data in tabular format no

Comment: remove `<tr>` before while loop, it is of no  use

Comment: You dont have a `<form.....>` tag in your code. `<input....>` fields only work if they are inside a form

Comment: removed but it s getting the same error

Comment: @user5836176  What is the exact issue that you are facing ?

Comment: i have form method action also getting same error

Comment: i need to edit the data and update the record while doing that iam getting this error which i posted

Comment: As i edited my code including form action and input type but getting the same error

Comment: Can anyone help me this please thanks in advance

Comment: @user5836176, please check my answer I hope it solves your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your syntax try using this code

```
<?php
  session_start();
?>
<?php
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
  if($username) { 
?>
  <h3> Welcome <?php echo $username; ?></h3>
<?php 
  } else { 
    echo "no"; 
  }
?>
<html>
  <body>        
    <table class="table table-hover">
     <form action="personalinfo.php" METHOD="POST"> 
      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $username;?>" name="email">
      <tr>
        <th><label for="first_name">Name</label></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <?php
        include "personalinfo.php";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>

          <tr>
          <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $row->first_name;?>" />  
          </tr>
       <?php }?>


      </table>
     </form>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: *"You have an error in your syntax try using this code"* - which is what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because there's a HTML tag in php code.
This line has issue, as it was written in PHP code:

```
 <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $row->first_name;?>" />
```

Try replacing the code with this :

```
    <?php
    include "personalinfo.php";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
      <tr> 
        <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $row->first_name;?>" />  
<!-- //or this can be used <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $row->first_name;?>" /> 
-->
       </tr>
    <?php
    }
     ?>
    </table>
```